# Can I get SCNNode position in SCNScene when I use "node.physicsBody.velocity"?

Tags: swift, xcode, scenekit, scnnode, scnscene

Is there any way to get position of SCNNode in SCNScene when I used `node.physicsBody.velocity` before? I have set default coordinates to `SCNVector3(0,0,0)` then I've used `node.physicsBody.velocity = SCNVector3(someValue, someValue, someValue)` and tried read it from `node.position` but It printed `SCNVector3(0,0,0)`.  Does `velocity` change node position in SCNScene? Or can I get node position in SCNScene?

Any ideas?

Comment: Try node.presentation.position.  It's the closest approximation to what's being displayed on the screen.

Comment: Thanks it helped :-)